# Does tf.lookupTransform (python) take time to fire up?

Tags: transforms, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I have an issue I don't understand with tf in Python. Consider this code:

```
import rospy, tf
rospy.init_node('test')
l = tf.TransformListener()
# rospy.sleep(0.5)
# l.waitForTransform('BODY', 'manipulation_marker', rospy.Time(0), rospy.Time(10))
print l.lookupTransform('BODY', 'manipulation_marker', rospy.Time(0))
```

When I run it, I get a LookupException:

```
LookupException: "BODY" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.
```

But if I uncomment the sleep() before the lookupTransform, it works fine.

So, I was thinking I could use the waitForTransform() function to replace this sleep() and get the transform as soon as it is available. (Next commented line.) But it doesn't work either and I get a generic Exception() with no error message!

To give you more information about my TF, here is the output from tf_monitor:

```
RESULTS: for BODY to manipulation_marker
Chain is: * -> * -> * -> BODY
Net delay     avg = 0.0424558: max = 0.0998758

All Broadcasters:
Node: unknown_publisher 111.186 Hz, Average Delay: -0.221831 Max Delay: 0.0471964
```

What should I do here to get the transform as soon as it is available?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207582/does-tf.lookuptransform-(python)-take-time-to-fire-up?/) by [Stephane Caron](https://answers.ros.org/users/21907/stephane-caron/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using waitForTransform is the right approach. There's an open ticket at the moment I think you're encountering. https://github.com/ros/geometry_experimental/issues/102

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephane Caron](https://answers.ros.org/users/21907/stephane-caron/) on 2015-04-24**:
Thanks, I will follow this.